# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Protocol error. Session setup failed

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

i am trying to connect to a postgresql server 9.3 running in my local machine.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.3-1100-jdbc41</version>
    </dependency>
```

Also tried above jar for Driver class.

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Protocol error. Session setup failed. 
  at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:510) 
  at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:173)
  at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:64) 
  at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:136) 
  at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:29)
```

resulted in above exception.
any idea how to ge around this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PostgreSQL "Protocol error. Session setup failed.." error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15471039/postgresql-protocol-error-session-setup-failed-error) among others.

Comment: Provide the username and password. How are you getting your `Connection`?

Comment: @BrianRoach I don't think so... that was a version mismatch; this looks like a failure in authentication.

Comment: Examine the PostgreSQL server error logs to see if there's a corresponding server-side error message.

Comment: the versions are correct. There was a typo in my connection string. the port given was wrong. After specifying the port, connection created successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the versions are correct. There was a typo in my connection string. the port given was wrong. After specifying the port, connection created successfully.